# Energy loss due to synchrotron radiation in linear and circular accelerators

Tags: particle-physics, particle-accelerators

Is the energy loss of an electron accelerated in a circular accelerator (with radius R and circumference $2\pi R $) the same as the energy loss in a linear accelerator over the same distance, if both are accelerated with the same strength magnetic field?

From my reasoning, the energy loss should be dependent only on the particle's mass and the accelerating magnetic field. I think the energy loss should be independent of the particle's trajectory. For some reason we have been moving from circular to linear electron colliders. What is a reason behind this change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This goes to the textbook definition of 'acceleration' as change in *velocity*: you presumably remember your teacher trying to convince you that when a cyclist went round a corner they were `accelerating' even though their speed was unchanged.

Likewise when an electron - or other charged particle- is bent by a magnet to give a roughly circular orbit, that is acceleration and produces synchrotron radiation. So circular accelerators/storage rings produce lots of synchrotron radiation - which is good for the solid state physicists and biologists who do nice experiments with it, but a pain for those trying to accelerate particles to high energie. This is why linear colliders, like the ILC, have been proposed.

BTW particles are not accelerated by magnetic fields (except in the obscure case of the betatron). They are accelerated by RF electric fields, and the dipole magnets bend them into a circular orbit, and quadrupole magnets focus them. There is some synchrotron radiation in a linac, from the (speed-changing) acceleration in the RF and the deflections in the focussing magnets, but it's much smaller than what comes out of bending magnets.